# Photoshop CC scripting: is it possible to find inline pseudoformatting in a TextItem?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, photoshop-scripting

I'm working with a large number of PSDs as the page masters for an ebook. The author of the book used pseudoformatting rather than the proper **bold** and *italic* versions of the font (Times New Roman), which doesn't carry over when I import all the PSDs into another application to compile them into a usable PDF.

I've looked into scripting (JS) to detect such inline pseudoformatting, but have not figured out if this is possible - it seems I can only detect such formatting if the entire TextItem is formatted.

Is there any way to detect inline **bold** and *italic* pseudoformatting in a PSD? The TextItem.content property doesn't appear to include this information.

Just to be clear: I'm referring to the faux **bold** and faux *italic* text formats:
[image]

Comment: Sounds like a nightmare. Both what you are doing right now and also to layout an entire book in Photoshop.

Comment: Just briefly looked at [the API](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/photoshop-latest/). It seems very limited when it comes to text. So far I agree with you that it's not possible, but other users might have some experience with it.

Comment: Impossible with DOM api, sort of possible with ActionManager code in PS but if you aren't familiar with it I wouldn't recommend diving in